# PHP - Difficulty working with array for dynamic creation

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I need a array like this one:

```
array('quadra_id'=>$quadra_id);
```

The deal is that I'll create it dynamically, according to what is sent by the form.

```
$where = array();

if($quadra_id != 0) {
   array_push($where, $quadra_id);
}
```

It returns me this:

```
array
  0 => string '8762' (length=3)
```

And I need this:

```
array
  'quadra_id' => string '8762' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_push adds the new element to the array with a numeric index, while what you want is a string index. So you actually want to do this:

```
$where['quadra_id'] = $quadra_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
array_push($where, $quadra_id);
```

With:

```
$where['quadra_id'] = $quadra_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to supply the index I would do it this way

```
$where = array();

if($quadra_id != 0) {
   $where['quadra_id']= $quadra_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line...

`array_push($where, $quadra_id);`

...with the following:

`$where ['quadra_id'] = $quadra_id;`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
array_push($where, array('quadra_id'=>$quadra_id));
```

If there's only going to be one, you should really just do:

```
if($quadra_id != 0) {    
  $where = array('quadra_id'=>$quadra_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set $where equal to $_POST. If you have other form inputs that should not be in $where, you can set them aside by putting them in an array in the input name, like this.

```
<input name='where[quadra_id]' value='' />
```

In this case, $where would be set to $_POST['where'].